# FPDF coordinates dont fit

Tags: fpdf

I am loading a PDF file using FPDI and try to place a PNG image inside the template. The original document units are in mm and 150ppi. When I set the image at the coordinates 50mm,50mm (50mm = 141,7323 px) the image is actually set 10px more right and 10px more bottom at 151,7323px. I set margings to 0. I set XY origin to 0,0. I have no idea whats going wrong.

```
// initiate FPDI
$pdf = new FPDI('L','mm');

// get the page count
$pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('../lib/handoutv1.pdf');
// iterate through all pages

// import a page
$templateId = $pdf->importPage(1);
// get the size of the imported page
$size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($templateId);

// create a page (landscape or portrait depending on the imported page size)
if ($size['w'] > $size['h']) {
    $pdf->AddPage('L', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
} else {
    $pdf->AddPage('P', array($size['w'], $size['h']));
}

// use the imported page
$pdf->useTemplate($templateId);

$pdf->SetMargins(0, 0, 0);
$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica');
$pdf->SetXY(5, 5);
$pdf->Write(8, 'A complete document imported with FPDI');
$pdf->SetXY(0, 0);
$pdf->Image('http://server.com/png.png',50,50,30,30,'PNG');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code looks ok. I guess you've a kind of margin in your image which leads to such effect, possible?

Comment: I bet for `$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false);` more than margins, at lest that fixed it for me. As you can see him set margins already :-)